# VBA for listing all files in folder or zip archive including subfolders

Tags: excel, vba, zip

I'm sharing my code for listing all subdirectories and files contained in a selected folder or ZIP archive.

I have been looking for such solution for a few days and only found flawed recursive scripts that stopped at listing the contents of the first subfolder, or missing the files in root folder, or only working for 2 levels of subfolders.

This scripts uses listing found items in the worksheet, marking them as directories or files so it can the loop through them and re-initiate the look through function for all newly found subfolder levels as it goes.

It uses shell application instead of DIR so it can be used also for searching contents of zip archives (Dir function sees ZIP as file, not directory)

I've tried to make it as lean as possible, but I'm more than happy if you can streamline it even further

```
Sub loop_through_files_in_subfolders()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim start_folder As Variant

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim CurrRow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

'set folder of choice or zip archive
start_folder = "C:\Makro_test\F1.zip"

'sets the selected path in colum A as initial directory and sets "D"irectory flag in column B
ws.Range("A2").Value2 = start_folder
ws.Range("B2").Value2 = "D"

'set current row as first under headers
CurrRow = 2

'set last row as first empty row
LastRow = 3

'continue until current row equals the first empty row (list has ended)
Do Until CurrRow = LastRow

'only do for rows containing a "D"irectory path
If ws.Range("B" & CurrRow).Value2 = "D" Then
    
    start_folder = ws.Range("A" & CurrRow).Value2 'set the folder to look through
    loop_through_items_in_folder start_folder, wb, ws 'execute the look through function
    ws.Range("A" & CurrRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'colour mark the cell containing searched folder

End If

CurrRow = CurrRow + 1 'set current row to next one

'update last row to include contents of the last searched folder
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Loop

End Sub


Function loop_through_items_in_folder(ITM_path As Variant, wb, ws)

Dim shell
Dim ITM, Sub_ITM

Dim LR As Long

Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

'use the provided path to set the folder
Set ITM = shell.Namespace(ITM_path)

'loop through all items in folder
For Each Sub_ITM In ITM.items

    'look for first empty row
    LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    'store file path in column A
    ws.Range("A" & LR).Value = Sub_ITM.path
    
    'store flag for "D"irectory or "F"ile in column B
    If Sub_ITM.isfolder Then
        ws.Range("B" & LR).Value = "D"
    Else
        ws.Range("B" & LR).Value = "F"
    End If


Next Sub_ITM

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this (using an Excel file with a zip extension added for testing):

```vb
Sub Tester()
    ListZipContents "C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip"
End Sub

Sub ListZipContents(zipFilePath As Variant)

    Dim oApp As Object, colFolders As New Collection, itm As Object, fld As Object

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    colFolders.Add oApp.Namespace(zipFilePath).self
    
    Do While colFolders.Count > 0
        Set fld = colFolders(1)     'get the first folder
        colFolders.Remove 1         '...and remove it from the collection
        For Each itm In oApp.Namespace(fld.Path).Items
            If itm.isfolder Then
                colFolders.Add itm   'save folder path for listing
            Else
                Debug.Print itm.Path 'list file path
            End If
        Next
    Loop
End Sub
```

Ouput:

```txt
C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip\[Content_Types].xml
C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip\_rels\.rels
C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip\xl\workbook.bin
C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip\xl\styles.bin
C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip\xl\sharedStrings.bin
C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip\xl\vbaProject.bin
C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip\docProps\core.xml
C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip\docProps\app.xml
C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip\xl\_rels\workbook.bin.rels
C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip\xl\worksheets\sheet1.bin
C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip\xl\worksheets\binaryIndex1.bin
C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip\xl\theme\theme1.xml
C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip\xl\printerSettings\printerSettings1.bin
C:\Temp\tempo.xlsb.zip\xl\worksheets\_rels\sheet1.bin.rels
```